# detachChild in runOnUpdateThread not working

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I try do this:

```
private void deleteFromScene(final GameObject objectToRemove) {
    mActivity.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            mMap.mScene.detachChild(objectToRemove.mSprite);

        }
    });

}
```

and this is not working. Maybe it not working bacause GameObject is final? So how I can do, what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GameObject being final should not be a problem. Try `mSprite.detachSelf();`